# How to add local web page link to a WSS portal?

Tags: sharepoint, wss

I have a website on the same server as WSS and I want to add a link to a page on that website inside WSS. 
Do I need to do programming for that or adding links is more like an administrative task?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add links pointing wherever you want. You can have for instance a link to an external site on your SharePoint navigation menu. It is all done using a browser. In this case it does not matter whether or not both sites are on the same box.

Comment: I got started on it and as you pointed out it can be done using the navigation menu. Thank you.